# Python: Access multi-dimensional list

Tags: python, list

I have the following list:

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
```

Now I want to access only the first elements of each sub-list:

```
a1 = [1,3,5]
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: `a1 = [i[0] for i in a]`

Comment: wow, that was fast! Thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate but you can either use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) `[x[0] for x in a]` or [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) function `list(zip(*a))[0]`.

Comment: that _is_ a duplicate, found it by googling in seconds. This kind of duplicate Q&mostly answering is kiling the site.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Try this:

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
b = [i[0] for i in a]
print(b)  # prints [1,3,5]
```